# Numpy sclicing multiple dimensions simulteanously

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Given a 2D array and two pairs of indices, defining the upper left and lower right corner of a sub-matrix respectively:

```
a = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
#        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
#        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
#        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
#        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
ij_ul = (1, 1)  # upper left
ij_lr = (4, 3)  # lower right
```

I can get the sub-matrix via:

```
a[ij_ul[0]:ij_lr[0], ij_ul [1]: ij_lr[1]]
# array([[ 6,  7],
#        [11, 12],
#        [16, 17]])
```

However I would like to use something more elegant like this:

```
a[ij_ul:ij_lr]  # Wish
# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

to slice all dimensions simultaneously. The first index in *ij_ul*, slices to the first index in *ij_lr*, and the second to the second.

I would like to use this for a function which should work for 2D and 3D.
Here such a formulation would be more general because there is no need of counting the dimensions and adjust the slicing:

```
a[i:j]  # 1D
a[i:j, k:l]  # 2D
a[i:j, k:l, n:m]  # 3D
a[tuple_1:tuple_2]  # Wish
```

The last line would always work if the arrray and the two index-tuples were
of matching dimension.

Is there something like slicing multiple dimensions simultaneously in python/numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have these two lists, we can construct a tuple as follows:

```
our_submatrix = a[tuple(map(slice, ij_ul, ij_lr))]
```

Here we iterate over the two iterables `ij_ul` and `ij_lr` concurrently, and we construct `slice(..)` objects (if you write `i:j` you actually construct such object behind the curtains).

So what we do here is constructing a tuple of slices, and we can pass this to `a` to construct a view with the specified slices.

For example:

```
>>> A = np.random.randn(5, 7)
>>> A
array([[-0.41526531,  0.88895983,  1.25061578, -0.01930474,  0.90183725,
         0.169831  , -0.67271614],
       [ 0.26148559, -1.24269541,  0.72472787, -2.75687495, -0.64511098,
        -1.5535446 ,  0.74714421],
       [ 0.8423359 ,  0.26620621,  0.26581058, -1.20667371,  0.60521744,
         2.02856815, -0.43339106],
       [ 0.29617257,  1.86195973, -1.33591589,  0.97233933, -0.69254736,
        -0.31652783,  0.78613453],
       [-0.93928881,  0.26735583, -0.27057705,  0.78084479, -0.76763169,
         0.12574734, -1.88236193]])
>>> A[tuple(map(slice, ij_ul, ij_lr))]
array([[-1.24269541,  0.72472787],
       [ 0.26620621,  0.26581058],
       [ 1.86195973, -1.33591589]])
```